# How to add consumer to Flux publisher on first api call

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, flux, react-native-router-flux

I am using the below api code for returning the `Flux<BiteEventsResponse>` , but seems when I start my application and do the first API call from postman due to no consumer for the Flux publisher my first API call is getting stuck for infinite time. The events are getting emitted when I do the 2nd api call.

As I understood this `Flux.create(eventsPublisher).share();` looks for any active consumer , as my application started and on the api call `/bites/events` triggered first time so no consumer. Or can we check the Flux publisher has no previous entry or consumer ? Any suggestion on this would be helpful ?

**BiteEventsController.java**

```
public class BiteEventsController {

    private final Flux<BiteEvent> biteEvent;
    private final int INTERVAL = 10;
    private final Flux<BiteEventsResponse> keepAlive = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(INTERVAL))
            .map(e -> new BiteEventsResponse("iam-alive", null));

    public BiteEventsController(BiteEventsPublisher eventsPublisher) {
        this.biteEvent = Flux.create(eventsPublisher).share();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/bites/events", produces = "text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8")
    public Flux<BiteEventsResponse> biteEvents(HttpServletRequest request) {        
        try {
            Flux<BiteEventsResponse> biteEvent = this.biteEvent.filter(
                    event -> (event.getOwnerId() != null ))
                    .map(event -> {                        
                        return new BiteEventsResponse("message", (BiteResponse) event.getSource());
                    });
            return Flux.merge(keepAlive, biteEvent);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("{}", ex);
            return Flux.empty();
        }
    }

}
```

**BitePublisher.java**

```
public class BiteEventsPublisher implements Consumer<FluxSink<BiteEvent>> {

@Autowired
BiteEventsPublisherConfig biteEventConfig;

@EventListener
public void onBiteEvent(BiteEvent event) {
    biteEventConfig.biteEventBlockingQueue().offer(event);
}

@Override
public void accept(FluxSink<BiteEvent> sink) {
    while (true)
        try {
            BiteEvent event = biteEventConfig.biteEventBlockingQueue().take();
            sink.next(event);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Bite events publisher failed {}", ex);
            break;
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Most of the code should not be necessary, i.e., in a normal situation you wouldn't need to `merge` it with anything. It looks like there is something in `BiteEventsPublisher` preventing it from a normal work. Can you share more details about this part?

Comment: Added the BiteEventsPublisher.

Comment: Its working fine when I trigger the api call 2nd time, but after my service start the very 1st call is not working.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Is there anything wrong with the publisher ?

Comment: What if you run the `while (true) {}` loop inside a new thread?

Comment: Not sure, how that help. Only the very first call is not working , 2nd call onwards its working fine.

Comment: But can you do that just as an experiment?

Comment: Sure, let me try. But is there any way we can check the event publisher "private final Flux<BiteEvent> biteEvent;"  is empty or has no consumer so that we can return Flux.empty() ?

Comment: Hi @IgorArtamonov, actually its working after adding the thread executor i.e. Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(()  -> {mycode while (true)} , its working fine.  A great help.. Thanks!

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, I just trying to understand the major difference with thread its working and without thread its now working. How that works ?

Comment: Well, I don't know for sure either. I hope someone more knowledgeable with Reactor internals may explain better, but my understanding that `sink.next(event)` cannot continue as it's the same thread where the subscription started because the subscription is now busy with the loop itself

Comment: Thanks @IgorArtamonov, you might be right.  I got simillar example here where he is implemented similar way FYI. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/creating-a-reactive-restful-api-with-spring-boot-e706954f0633